# Why do Photo diodes in Computer Mouses don't generate electricity when receiving light?

Tags: visible-light, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

I had been researching about photovoltaic cells recently for a science project.
In my researches,I stumbled upon photovoltaic cells,silicons,solar cells,and photodiodes.
Photodiodes and Solar panels are both photovoltaic cells as what I found in my inquiries.That means they use photons to generate electron flow.But one thing that bothered me are photodiodes.
When I kept researching about photodiodes I found several videos about people using photodiodes found in Computer Mouses as Alarms and sensors,and as what they have showed in their demonstrations and experiments the loads like the red LED
Attached to the Mouse's Motherboard does not accept power when displayed to a light source.it only glows when the light is blocked.
Can someone explain to me why that happens?
Thank you.

Comment: If you have a device that allows current in light's presence, you can make a very simple circuit with just one transition to invert the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the bias circuit.

A photodiode under illumination has the following current voltage curve with three regimes:

1. Photo-detector, in reverse bias power is put into the diode and it can be used a photo detector
2. Solar cell, in this regime of weak forward bias, power flows *out* of the circuit
3. LED, is strong forward bias, power is put *into* the diode and it emits light.

Without more details we cannot help with the specifics of your case, but this is the *fundamental physics*. If you change the bias circuit you should be able to move any LED between these three regimes. Obviously an LED is designed to work best at emitting light, so it will probably operated poorly in the other regimes.

[image: diode IV]